# importing javax packages in android?

Tags: java, android, security

I am facing problem with some packages like Javax, when i am trying to import the following packages in my android applications!

```
Javax.naming.Naming.Exception; 
Javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
Javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;

 private DirContext connectLDAP()
    throws NamingException
 {
    Properties localProperties = new Properties();
    localProperties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", LDAP_PROVIDER);
    localProperties.setProperty("java.naming.batchsize", "0");
    localProperties.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", this.params.getLdapURL());
    localProperties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.jndi.url");
    localProperties.setProperty("java.naming.referral", REFERRALS_IGNORE);
    localProperties.setProperty("java.naming.security.authentication", "none");
    return new InitialDirContext(localProperties);
}
```

help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The classes that you are trying to use are not part of [the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html). You will need to find some other solution for whatever problem it is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: I thought so but this(http://www.zdnet.com/article/java-vs-android-apis/) made me confused. And I've also seen many people who were using javax.sound on Android.. I don't understand how and why.

Comment: @JenixGuy: "made me confused" -- that is an eight-year-old article, and there has been some shifting since then (e.g., we have a tiny slice of `java.beans` now). I don't recall `javax.sound` ever being in Android.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the clarification, now I got it!